# ВКП (б) или ВКП(б)?

Tags: пунктуация, аббревиатуры, пробелы

Как правильно: с пробелом или без?

Answer (score 1):

Инициальные аббревиатуры пишутся прописными буквами: ООН, МИД, РФ. Точки или пробелы между буквами не ставятся, но между двумя самостоятельно употребляющимися аббревиатурами используется пробел: ИРЯ РАН, МИД РФ.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/60-rubric-91

Поэтому правильно будет **ВКП(б)** (без пробела).

Comment: Здесь нужна аргументация в обоснование отсутствия пробела перед открывающей скобкой в аббревиатуре, поскольку по общему правилу перед открывающей скобкой пробел ставится. Из отсутствия пробела между буквами сделанный вывод не следует.

Comment: Ага, Александр прав. А вопрос возник потому, что я на Википедии увидел написание с пробелом и задумался, правильно ли так.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, на Википедии, как и в других источниках, употребляется написание без пробела. Вот пара примеров навскидку: [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Коммунистическая_партия_Советского_Союза#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), [ещё вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Оргбюро_ЦК_ВКП%28б%29), [словари](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/72305/ВКП).

Comment: А я видел как раз с пробелом на ней!

Answer (score 1):

Поискал в интернете. На фотографиях документов той эпохи (например, бланков ЦК ВКП(б), обложек книг) ясно видно, что пробела нет. А вот в Нацкорпусе везде пробелы. Надо полагать, правила изменились.

Comment: Я думаю, просто стали за этим следить. Правила-то и раньше не допускали скобок без предшествующего пробела.

Answer (score 0):

Российская социал-демократическая рабочая партия — **РСДРП** — образована в 1898 году в Минске. В 1903 году произошло разделение на **РСДРП(б)** и **РСДРП(м)** — большевиков и меньшевиков.

[**РСДРП(о)**](https://sokrasheniya.academic.ru/5070/%D0%A0%D0%A1%D0%94%D0%A0%D0%9F%28%D0%BE%29) — объединённая (1917);

Российская коммунистическая партия (большевиков) — [**РКП(б)**](https://sokrasheniya.academic.ru/22906) — 1918—1925;

Всесоюзная коммунистическая партия (большевиков) — **ВКП(б)** — 1925—1952;

Коммунистическая партия (большевиков) Эстонии — **КП(б)Э** — 1940 — 1952.

Всё просто и абсолютно правильно **без** пробелов:
**К**оммунистическая **п**артия (**б**ольшевиков) **Э**стонии = **КП(б)Э.**
Удалены пробелы между отдельными словами (это большие буквы) и словом в скобках (это маленькая буква), что вполне соответствует правилам образования аббревиатур. А они никоим образом не изменялись (см. ссылки — 2015г.).
Была и такая аббревиатура: **КП(б)ЛиБ** (Литва и Белоруссия,1919 — 1920).
Представить себе раздельное написание, например, **КП (б) Э** или **КП (б) У** (Украины) просто невозможно.

Comment: Мне тоже вариант без пробелов кажется естественным. Но в Нацкорпусе находим как раз то, что, по-Вашему, представить себе невозможно: В мае 1941-го СНК Молдавской ССР и ЦК **КП (б) М** представили свои предложения по развитию виноградарства, плодоовощных и масличных культур в республике. [Константин Дроздов. Внелимитные затраты // «Родина», 2010]

Comment: Сам Брежнев так писал: Наконец, вышли решение ЦК ВКП (б) и связанное с ним решение **ЦК КП (б) У** «О подготовке, подборе и распределении руководящих партийных и советских кадров в украинской партийной организации». [Л. И. Брежнев. Возрождение (1980)]

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вечер добрый, Артём! Жаль, что мой ответ тебе не понравился... Но вот "настоящее" предложение из "Возрождения" (я частенько проверяю то, что имеется в Нацкорпусе): *Наконец, вышли решение **ЦК ВКП(б)** и связанное с ним решение **ЦК КП(б)У**...* (https://royallib.com/read/bregnev_leonid/vozrogdenie.html#0)